# why does java allow this?

Tags: java, syntax, semantics

it is syntactically legal to do this:

```
String [] s = new String[1];
Object [] o = s;

o[0] = new Integer(42);
```

but of course it will crash at runtime.

my question is: what is the point of allowing this assignment in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the assignment `Object [] o = s;` - I assume that's what you mean by "this".

The technical term is [array covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Arrays_in_C.23_and_Java), and without it, you could not have code that deals with arrays generically. For example, most of the non-primitive-array methods in `java.util.Arrays` would be useless as you could only use them with actual `Object[]` instances. Obviously, this was considered more important by the designers of Java than complete type safety.

There is an alternative solution, which you see when looking at Java's generics introduced in Java 5: explicit covariance via wildcards. However, that results in considerable added complexity (see the constant stream of questions about the `?` wildcard), and Java's original designers wanted to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The point of allowing that kind of assignment is that disallowing it would make things like the following impossible:

```
ArrayList[] lists = new ArrayList[10];
lists[0] = new ArrayList();

List[] genericLists = lists;
lists[0].add("someObject");
```

If the compiler forbids your String -> Object case, then it would also have to forbid ArrayList -> List and any other instance of assigning from a subclass to one of its superclass types.  That kind of makes a lot of the features of an object-oriented language such as Java useless.  Of course, it's much more typical to do things like:

```
List[] lists = new List[10];
lists[0] = new ArrayList();
lists[0].add("someObject");
```

But regardless, the compiler can't filter out these cases without simultaneously disallowing many useful and legitimate use-cases, so it's up to the programmer to make sure that what they are doing is sane.  If what you want is an `Object[]`, then declare your variable as such.  If you declare something as `String[]`, cast it to an `Object[]`, and then forget that what you really have is a `String[]`, then that is simply programmer error.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed, you get a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer` when you run that code

The compiler allows it, because you're casting a String[] to Object[], which is correct. This is similar to

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
Object o = i;
String s = (String) o;
```

The compiler doesn't complain, but you get a ClassCastExeption at runtime.

Comment: but you're not answering the question at all.  You're simply re-stating exactly what the OP stated.  Also the OP never said it was *"allowed"*, the OP said that it was *"syntactically"* correct and that it was crashing at runtime.  The OP's well-formulated question is very clear and your answer doesn't answer anything...

Comment: I'm just showing that the compiler doesn't generate an error or warning by showing an analogy with objects. Even more, ArrayStoreException is the equivalent to a ClassCastExeception when assigning values to an array, as they are thrown when a type is not compatible. But please feel free to disagree :).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't know (without static analysis) that `o` is actually a `String[]` and so allows the assignment even though it fails at runtime. There's nothing preventing a e.g. `Integer[]` to be assigned to `o`, it just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment must be allowed because the compiler cannot infer if the array will hold (or will not hold) only strings at runtime. It throws an `[ArrayStoreException][1]` which is checked at runtime.

Consider this:

```
String [] s = new String[1];
Object [] o = s;

o = new Integer[1];

o[0] = new Integer(1);
```

This situation is valid and runs OK. To give a more broader perspective, IMHO Arrays are a low-level leaky abstraction in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the compiler can't tell if `o` has been assigned as `String[]`. Consider this:

```
String[] s = new String[1];
Object[] o;

if (complexFunction(System.currentTimeMillis())) {
  o = s;
} else {
  o = new Integer[1];
}

o[0] = 42;
```

The compiler won't know at design time what type `o` is going to take - so it just allows the assignment.